# Can't sign up a new Facebook account for my business

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, registration

I need to create a Facebook account for my business, so I tried to sign up with my business email and it didn't let me! The error message is:

> We require everyone to use their real name on Facebook. If you'd like to add an alternate name, you may do so after registration. Learn more.

But I am using my real name.

Could someone help to point out how do I sign up an account for my business use, please?

Comment: You're using your real personal name, not 'John AwesomeCompany Smith' or anything like that? There should be a process to provide proof of your name if it's especially suspicious (if your name overlaps with a celebrity, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Create one personal profile for yourself, using your real name. Or log in to your own personal Facebook account. Then you can create a Facebook page for this business.

Source: [How are Pages different from personal profiles?](https://www.facebook.com/help/217671661585622)